# What do the Skull and Crossbones icons over the heads mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

[image: Screenshot of an elite and minions with skull and crossbones icons over their heads]

We have run across this skull and crossbones icon over a few enemies in Hell difficulty and we don't really know what it is. It doesn't appear to be consistent with effect names on elites. I did notice my character had a debuff in the screenshot (didn't notice it in game) and also has the skull and crossbones over his head. So what is this thing and what effects does it have on the monsters and the players?

Comment: Messed up the formatting pretty hard when I first posted that, lol.

Comment: If you mouseover the spell on your buff/debuff bar if will show a tooltip.  Also, you are only referring to the skull and crossbones, *not* the blue glyph above the boss?

Comment: I didn't notice the debuff while we were fighting to actually hover over and look at it :(. And yea, Only the skull and crossbones. Blue glyph above the boss is Demon Hunter's mark ability. I'll clarify title.

Comment: That is one sexy dead barbarian

Comment: You're worried about icons while your friend is seriously stuck?!

Comment: @Snailer Don't worry, she eventually managed to get through her roadblock. :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked around and it seems that it is indeed the [enrage timer](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149539296#1) that is activated when you fight monsters for too long.

> If you fight a boss or champ pack for too long they hit a soft enrage where you take damage every second for standing near them

I haven't ever seen it in Nightmare, so it looks like the debuff can occur in Hell or Inferno.

Answer (score 5):

This is the enrage of the mob. After a while it will enrage and do dmg to all around it. Only occurs in hell and inferno mode.

We were able to reset it by leaving the dungeon for a while (cannot say a clear number).

Comment: This picture was taken in Hell difficulty...

Comment: Sorry about that, edited my answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, that's Out of Time. If you fight a Champion or Elite pack for too long in Hell or Inferno, you'll get it (usually because your entire team is respawning and charging the same pack over and over) - it deals damage over time that slowly escalates, and causes the pack to regenerate to full life as soon as they're no longer engaged.