# Rare monster with a strange ability and a skull icon on top of it

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the Skull and Crossbones icon over heads mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68663/what-does-the-skull-and-crossbones-icon-over-heads-mean)

I was attacking a rare monster, and it was nearly dead, but I died before I could finish it off. When I saw the monster again I saw a skull, and my character started taking 2k damage per second out of nowhere, and I died over and over. What is happening?

Comment: that would be its 'enrage timer'

Comment: It's 'fun'. Right?

Answer (score 1):

If, after five minutes of fighting, you have not killed an elite, it will [Enrage](http://www.diablowiki.net/Enrage_Timer).  This will apply a debuff to your character that causes you to take damage over time.  The debuff is removed when the elite is killed or you leave the area, allowing it to regenerate to full health.  If you're fighting a champion pack, killing just one of the champions will remove the debuff and reset the timer.